# Run apps in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to make application, in which are used icons of some social sites, like facebook.

So the application looks like:

[image]

If you click on Facebook:

```
public void Facebook_Click()
{
    **Here must be code to detect installed applications**
    if (detected=true)
    {
          RunApplication (facebook);
    }
    else
    {
          OpenBrowser on page Facebook.com
    }
}
```

**How to detect installed apps and run them?**

Before saying it is impossible:

Auto-launching apps using file and URI associations for Windows Phone 8:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx

**Maybe someone tried this?**

Comment: You can remove the Windows-phone-7 tags then, file and URI associations are only available for Windows Phone 8

Comment: The URI associations needs to be implemented in any app that wishes to be launched/interacted with by other apps. It is not a way for you to detect installed apps on the user's phone.

Comment: unfortunately it's impossible. You can't get the list of installed apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no way to know what App are installed on the user's phone. You can open a link in web browser, but cannot do that with apps that haven't got URI associations as Alaa Masoud said.